# Spring Boot Apache Derby Duplicate Key Value Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, derby

Seeing this Exception:

[image]

This is my POST Request.
[image]

I tried with different key value pairs. Still the same error.

My Entity Class.

[image]

**Error**
The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL200516190100880' defined on 'DATA_STORE'.

Anything I could be missing?

Comment: The error message is telling you that a row with those values already exists in your database.

Comment: Thanks! My class was not POJO, so it was passing it as null object and insert null object all the time. Hence this duplicate error. I was passing unique values all the time to the program.